# mongodb - How is a replica set contacted if the configured instance is down?

Tags: mongodb, replication

Let's imagine we have:

- 1 replica set with 2 data instances (rs0_0 and rs0_1) and a arbiter instance (rs0_2).
- 3 config servers instances (cfg0, cfg1 and cfg2).
- 1 mongos instance (mos0).

After all the instances have been launched (rs0_0, rs0_1, rs0_0, cfg0, cfg1, cfg2, mos0), we configure the replica set:

```
mongo rs0_0_host:rs0_0_port
    rs.initiate()

    cfg = rs.conf()
    cfg.members[0].priority = 100              (rs0_0 will be the primary if alive)
    rs.reconfig(cfg)

    rs.add("rs0_1_host:rs0_1_port")
    rs.addArb("rs0_2_host:rs0_2_port")         (arbiter)
```

And then we add the replica set (as a shard) to the cluster:

```
mongo mos0_host:mos0_port
    use admin
    db.runCommand({ addShard: "rs0/rs0_0_host:rs0_0_port", maxSize: 400000, name: "shard_rs0" })
```

Now let's suppose that whole the cluster (all instances) go down, and then all instances get up except rs0_0. How is the replica set (the shard) contacted?

I mean: My application (or mongo shell) connects to mos0, mos0 asks to config servers (cfg0, cfg1 and/or cfg2), config servers return "rs0/rs0_0_host:rs0_0_port" (due to the "addShard" command we did run) from their config, then mos0 tries to connect to "rs0_0_host:rs0_0_port", but it can't because rs0_0 is down. So, how does mos0 know about the existence of rs0_1 and rs0_2 (the replica set instances that are alive)?

Of course, we could have configured the shard in this way:

```
    db.runCommand({ addShard: "rs0/rs0_0_host:rs0_0_port,rs0_1_host:rs0_1_port,rs0_2_host:rs0_2_port", maxSize: 400000, name: "shard_rs0" })
```

In that way, the mos0 would receive the full list of replica set instances from the config servers. But, since MongoDB 2.0.3, only one instance (of the replica set) is required to be especified in the "addShard" command. So where is the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mongos` in this case would hold an internal mapping of the relpica set within memory which is refreshed once every so often (just like drivers), at which point when the members start to come online it will do some checks and what not to detect which member it should contact. It cannot write to a member until there is, of course, a primary.

A seed list is good if you restart the mongos and the configured member is offline, at which point the mongos can take another member as the seed.

Comment: Your last paragraph is exactly what I meant.

A MongoS instance has no database, so if it goes offline, it won't remember the members of a shard (in fact, it won't remember anything). If all instances of the cluster (included all mongoS instances) go offline, and then all instances go back online except the shard member (rs0_0) that is stored at the config servers (for example, because the o.s. went corrupt), then the mongoS instance won't know how to contact the other instances (rs0_1 and rs0_2) of the shard (that are online!).

Comment: So the CONCLUSION I get is: It is safer to put all shard members into the "addShard" command, instead of putting only one member. Do you believe it should be a recommendation at mongodb web (for example, at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/addShard/ )?

Comment: @freesoft It might need to be added to the documentation on addShard, however, it does exist somewhere in the actual sharding documentation but yes, it never hurts to put it in a seeable place